# Get MAC address and interface name of network card

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, network-programming, ip

My workstation has a couple of network cards, which usually have default interface names like this: *local area connection*, *local area connection 2*, etc.

It may be that network card 1 is named *local area connection 3*, network card 2 is named *local area connection* etc.

I am trying to write a batch (preferred) or vbs script which does the following:

1. Check, whether a specific network card is installed in the machine which has one of the MAC addresses of a predefined list
2. Get the interface name of this network card
3. Change the interface name of that network card
4. Change the configuration of the network card (IP address, subnet mask)

So far, I found out that I could change the interface name using the command line:

```
netsh interface set interface name="local area connection" newname="newNetworkName"
```

and that I could change the configuration using:

```
netsh int ip set address "local area connection" static 192.168.0.101 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0
```

So the question now is how to realize step 1. and step 2.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: If you want to do this only for your workstation, why do you not open __Control Panel - Network and Sharing Center__ click on left side on __Change adapter settings__, rename the network adapters via context menu and change the IPv4 and/or IPv6 settings via context menu item __Properties__?

Comment: Right ;) No, I want to do it one many other workstations as soon as I got it to run on my own one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using `ipconfig /all` on a system with English system language:

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set MACLIST=01-02-03-04-05-06 AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ipconfig /all') do (
      set line=%%a
      if not "!line:~0,1!"==" " if not "!line:adapter=!"=="!line!" (
          set name=!line:*adapter =!
          set name=!name::=!
      )
      for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%b in ("%%a") do (
          if "%%b %%c"=="Physical Address." (
              set mac=%%d
              set mac=!mac:*: =!
              echo !name!: !mac!
              call set mactest=%%MACLIST:!mac!=%%
              if not "!MACLIST!"=="!mactest!" (
                  netsh interface set interface name="!name!" newname="newNetworkName1"
                  netsh int ip set address "newNetworkName1" static 192.168.0.101 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0
              )
          )
      )
  )
  pause
  ```
- Using `getmac` (takes 1 sec to execute though), language-independent:

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set MACLIST=01-02-03-04-05-06 AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('getmac /fo csv /nh /v') do (
      set line=%%a&set line=!line:"=,!
      for /f "delims=,,, tokens=1,3" %%b in ("!line!") do (
          set name=%%b
          set mac=%%c
          call set mactest=%%MACLIST:!mac!=%%
          if not "!MACLIST!"=="!mactest!" (
              netsh interface set interface name="!name!" newname="newNetworkName1"
              netsh int ip set address "newNetworkName1" static 192.168.0.101 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0
          )
      )
  )
  pause
  ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! This works perfectly! I used the solution with getmac. Would it be possible to check whether the MAC address is within a list of valids MAC adresses instead of checking against one specific address (without touching the code too much)?

Comment: @Rickson1982, how do you define/input the list of valid MACs?

Comment: @wOxxOm: Hi, I thought of sth. like that: set list = "01-02-03-04-05-06 AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF" etc.